# How to connect to Xorg on local network

Tags: linux, xorg, arch-linux

In my home network, my desktop is running Arch and my laptop is also running Arch Linux.

I want to be able to connect to desktop PC from my laptop. Similar to Window's remote desktop.

How should I set things up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two questions. :-)

Similar to remote desktop: Use e.g. [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) or similar software.

You *can* both setup the X server to work via the network, or forward X connections securely via `ssh`, but this still differentiates client/server (the X server on computer A will act as display server for new programs started on computer B), so it's probably not what you want.